# When would be the right time to end a Flurry session?

Tags: android, session, android-activity, flurry

I just have a normal app with a few activities, and I want Flurry to log information as well as crashes. When would be the best time to end the session? Should I do it in `onPause`, `onStop`, or `onDestroy`? In all of them or none?

According to the documentation, `onPause` and `onStop` are always called when exiting an app unless the app crashes or is destroyed by the user using a task killer. However, if I do put the end session in `onDestroy`, it will rarely be called.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the application class and put it in there:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onTerminate() {     
    super.onTerminate();

    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {        
    super.onCreate();

    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "123456789abcdefghi");

        // assign your global error handler here as well.


}

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I was going to do this but the doc specifically says not to: "We recommend using the onStart method of each Activity in your application, and passing the Activity (or Service) itself as the Context object - passing the global Application context is not recommended."

Comment: Also, will onTerminate do the same thing as onDestroy for an activity? I'm afraid of my users using a task killer and I won't get my analytics data.